# Executions per second calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

I just can't wrap my head around it. Thinking about getting some basic math courses cause it has been so long..

- A user executes at a speed of 10 000 000 per second.
- I have 100 000 users over the course of a month.
- Each user only executes for 1 minute per month.

What's the derived executions per second of all my combined users over the course of one month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  Each user executes how many operations (1 minute at their speed)?  Given the number of users, how many operations is that per month?  Now divide by the number of seconds per month.

Comment: That's actually not alot ;/ 0,02281591775317968333787750361917

Comment: I get a much higher number, around $2.3 \cdot 10^7$  If you show your calculation I can check it.

Comment: I was expressing myself in Giga units. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: 10 000 000 * 60 = 600 000 000 *  100 000 / 2 629 743 = 22815917

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.  Your previous comment looked like $2.28 \cdot 10^{-2}$.  I also used a $30$ day month, which accounts for our slight discrepancy.